# React component property is being updated by connect and data store but are not displayed

Tags: reactjs, redux

While debugging the following component using React and Redux tools I see that the store is being updated properly as well as the internal relevant property 'meals' is being updated with correct data, nonetheless, the component is not being updated on screen.

```
class MealEditView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { editedMeal: this.props.editedMeal };
    this.resetValuesForDisplay = this.resetValuesForDisplay.bind(this);
  }

  resetValuesForDisplay(editedMeal) {
    editedMeal = editedMeal !== undefined ? editedMeal : new Meal();
    let meal = new Meal();
    meal.calories = editedMeal.calories !== undefined ? editedMeal.calories : '';
    meal.description = editedMeal.description !== undefined ? editedMeal.description : '';
    meal.date = editedMeal.date !== undefined ? editedMeal.date : '';
    return meal;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Card className="side-form d-none">
          <CardHeader>
            <CardTitle tag="h4">Horizontal Form</CardTitle>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>
            <Form className="form-horizontal">
              <Row>
                <Label md="3">Title</Label>
                <Col md="9">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Input
                      placeholder="Title"
                      type="text"
                      value={this.props.editMeal !== undefined ? this.props.editedMeal.title : ''}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Label md="3">Calories</Label>
                <Col md="9">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Input
                      placeholder="Calories"
                      type="number"
                      key={this.props.editMeal !== undefined ? this.props.editedMeal.calories : ''}
                      value={this.props.editMeal !== undefined ? this.props.editedMeal.calories : ''}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Label md="3">Date</Label>
                <Col md="9">
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      autoComplete="off"
                      value={this.props.editMeal !== undefined ? this.props.editedMeal.date : ''}
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Row>
                <Col md="3" />
                <Col md="9">
                  <FormGroup check>
                    <Label check>
                      <Input type="checkbox" />
                      <span className="form-check-sign" />
                      Remember me
                    </Label>
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Form>
          </CardBody>
          <CardFooter>
            <Row>
              <Col md="3" />
              <Col md="9">
                <Button className="btn-round" color="info" type="submit">
                  Sign in
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = storeData => ({
  editedMeal: storeData.meals.editedMeal,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

const connectedMealsTable = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(MealEditView);
export default connectedMealsTable;
```

And the reducer :

```
export const DietActionReducer = (storeData, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    // case DIET_ACTION_TYPES.MEAL_ADD: {
    //     let newStoreData = {...storeData};
    //     let meals = newStoreData['meals'];
    //     meals[action.payload.meal.getId()] = action.payload.meal;
    //     break;
    // }
    case DIET_ACTION_TYPES.MEAL_EDIT: {
      let newStoreData = { ...storeData };
      let editedMeal = storeData.dataTable.find(meal => meal.id === action.payload);
      newStoreData.editedMeal = editedMeal;
      return newStoreData;
    }
    default:
      return storeData || {};
  }
};
```

What can please cause this ?

I apologize there is lots of code -most of it is just HTML ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can please cause this ?

Just a typo:

Change `editMeal` to be `editedMeal` based on your `mapStateToProps()`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.props.editMeal` to `this.props.editedMeal` in your `render()` method.
 For this line `this.state = { editedMeal: this.props.editedMeal };`  
use `UNSAFE_componentWillreceiveprops()` if you want to update state when props get updated but here no need to use it because you are using redux.